# convert SQL Query with Join to X++ Dynamics AX scripting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, axapta, x++

I have a SQL query that is not that simple as it contains Join

```
SELECT *
 FROM table1 a inner join table2 b on a.field1 = b.field1
 inner join table3 c on a.field2 = c.field2 
 inner join table4 d on c.field3 = d.field3
  inner join table5 e on c.field4 = e.field4
 WHERE a.location = 'asia' AND  b.modType = 1
 and c.discount = 'sample'
 and d.name =  'hello' 
and e.name in ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

I like to convert it to X++ scripting, here's what I did

```
  while select forUpdate 
        table1  join table2 where table1.field1 == table2.field1 
        join table3 where table1.field2 == table3.field2
        join table4 where table3.field3 == table4.field3
        join table5 where table3.category == table5.recid

        && table1.location  == 'asia' && table2.modtye == 2
        && table3.discount == 'sample' 
        && table4.name ==  'hello' 
       && table5.name in  ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

I need to retrieve the data to update

But the x++ is wrong and unsuccessful.

Hope to get expert advice on this as I am new to X++ scipting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of X++ do not support the *in* operator. Use *||* instead.
It is supported in a restricted form described [here](http://dev.goshoom.net/en/2018/12/in-operator-in-d365fo/), only supported for enums.

Also you will need to declare your buffers:

```
Table1 table1;
Table2 table2;
Table3 table3;
Table4 table4;
Table5 table5;
while select forUpdate table1  
    join table2 where table1.field1 == table2.field1 
    join table3 where table1.field2 == table3.field2
    join table4 where table3.field3 == table4.field3
    join table5 where table3.category == table5.recid
      && table1.location  == 'asia' && table2.modtye == 2
      && table3.discount == 'sample' 
      && table4.name ==  'hello' 
      &&(table5.name == 'one' || table5.name == 'two' || table5.name == 'three')
{
    info(strFmt('%1 %2 %3', table5.name, table4.name, table3.discount));
}
```

Comment: Hello, it is not returning correct count... pls see this for further description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319538/x-script-that-do-not-return-correct-count

Comment: Consider accepting the answer as it fixed the problem in you description.

Comment: hello, i cant verify yet if that is the correct counterpart of the sql query.. let me do that later once i further check

Comment: accepting this, because as per the question, this answers the correct counterpart of the sql query stated