# x++ script that do not return correct count

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, axapta, x++

I have a x++ script which aims to count records from a select query and later on be updated.

This is the original question for reference: [convert SQL Query with Join to X++ Dynamics AX scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290283/convert-sql-query-with-join-to-x-dynamics-ax-scripting/56297880#56297880)

Initially, I have a SQL Query counterpart of it and it is resulting to 50 rows / records, when I convert it to X++ , it is not counting or extracting the same number of records,

Here is is the x++ script

```
static void Job(Args _args)
{

    Table1 table1;
    Table2 table2;
    Table3 table3;
    Table4 table4;
    Table5 table5;
    int i = 0;
    while select forUpdate table1  
       join table2 where table1.field1 == table2.field1 
       join table3 where table1.field2 == table3.field2
       join table4 where table3.field3 == table4.field3
       join table5 where table3.category == table5.recid
       && table1.location  == 'asia' && table2.modtye == 2
       && table3.discount == 'sample' 
       && table4.name ==  'hello' 
       &&(table5.name == 'one' || table5.name == 'two' || table5.name == 'three')                
    {    
            if (table1)    
            {
                 i = i + 1;    
            }    
    }    
    info(strfmt("Total : %1",i));    
}
```

Pls help, where did i go wrong it think it's with this part

```
if (table1)
```

I also tried trimming down the codes to know where the problem arise,

```
 while select forUpdate table1  
           join table2 where table1.field1 == table2.field1 
           && table1.location  == 'asia' && table2.modtye == 2
```

This part dont return result already... when I include the

```
 && table1.location  == 'asia' && table2.modtye == 2
```

So i think, the problem is there, but what is wrong with the code?

---

I based my codes actually from this tutorial link

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/dynamicsaxtipoftheday/archive/2014/09/05/quickly-update-data-through-x-scripts

Comment: Should it be - if (table1)?

Comment: yes yes.. i edited already. still dont work

Comment: i have edited my question for some findings

Comment: You can check the SQL script for same logic that return data when execute directly in database.

Comment: i did already, the sql script is in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290283/convert-sql-query-with-join-to-x-dynamics-ax-scripting/56297880#56297880

Comment: I removed you try/catch, they made no difference.

Comment: ok... removing try catch is fine, but still no good

Comment: i think it's with the "JOIN" what should be the counterpart of inner join from SQL to X++? I used inner join in sql, i tried outer join in x++ and it is having a count already.. better than no count at all from "join" only in x++

Comment: "inner join" in SQL match "join" in X++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a simple explanation, maybe the SQL returns rows from a several companies or partitions?
AX by default returns row for the current partition and company `curext()` only.

If you use the `crosscompany` option to the select it will scan cross companies:

```
while select crosscompany table1 ...
```

You do not need to test whether table1 is found, if not found it will not enter the loop.

Also, if your sole purpose is to count the number of records it is wasteful to count manually, a single select will do:

```
select firstOnly /*crosscompany*/ count(RecId) from table1  
   exists join table2 where table1.field1 == table2.field1 
   exists join table3 where table1.field2 == table3.field2
   exists join table4 where table3.field3 == table4.field3
   exists join table5 where table3.category == table5.recid
     && table1.location  == 'asia' && table2.modtye == 2
     && table3.discount == 'sample' 
     && table4.name ==  'hello' 
     &&(table5.name == 'one' || table5.name == 'two' || table5.name == 'three');
info(strfmt("Total : %1", table1.RecId));
```

Comment: I see, but my goal is actually to update record based on the result set of the query. I just tried to simplify the question by creating a counter to test also if my result set in SQL is match with that of X++ counterpart. so when it is matched already, i can confidently update the record.

Comment: Okay, consider the first part of the answer.
Usually you want to restrict the updates to current company, so crosscompany in this context is not a good idea.

Comment: i'm sorry what is the recommended answer? i should use the crosscompany?

Comment: If you use crosscompany it may have the same count as your SQL. But do you really want to update all records irrespective of company?

Comment: actually, i also put this line: table1.location  == 'asia'  because this will filter out a per company criteria, so it will only incude result which comes from "asia" location....that location signifies the company

Comment: are there other ways which I can update a record which can be retrieved by doing such joins?

Comment: What is the best way then to update a specific record using x++ scripting which can be retrieve using multiple joins?

Comment: `update_recordset` but you will have to fix your query anyway.

Comment: hi Jan, it worked now, it is now match... your recommendation works..... im accepting this.

Comment: but as you mentioned, i can't use this to update? will i have a future problem when I do? pls advise..

Comment: Do not use crosscompany when updating. Run job in each company. Do not use `a.dataareaId == b.dataareaid` as this is implicit in X++,

Comment: Can you give idea on how to achieve it without using crosscompany? the one idea i know is using select forupdate crosscompany, retrieve all the records to be updated and update it... do you mean using update_recordset instead? can you give hints or ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: what's the disadvantage if i update using crossCompany, will it compromise the data overall? anyway, i created new question about update best practice in x++. hope you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323820/alternative-way-of-updating-record-in-x